# how to insert data from sql server to power bi graph after publish on web

Tags: powerbi

i am using power bi report in my project but i need my graph be change according to SQL server data. it means when we will insert new data in SQL server it effect my graph.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Microsoft has already given the [Documentation](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-sql-server-analysis-services-tabular-data/) regarding it.

> **SQL Server Analysis Services live data in Power BI**
>
> In Power BI, there are two ways you can connect to a live SQL Server
>   Analysis Services server. In Get data, you can connect to a SQL Server
>   Analysis Services server, or you can connect to a [Power BI Desktop
>   file](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-powerbi-desktop-files/), or [Excel workbook](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-excel-workbook-files/), that already connects to an Analysis
>   Services server.
>
> **Important :**
>
> - In order to connect to a live Analysis Services server, an On-premises Data Gateway must be installed and configured by an
>     administrator. For more information, see [On-premises Data
>     Gateway](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-gateway-onprem/).
> - When you use the gateway, your data remains on-premises.  The reports you create based on that data are saved in the Power BI
>     service.
> - [Q&A natural language querying](https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-service-q-and-a-direct-query/) is in preview for Analysis Services live connections.
>
> ### To connect to a model from Get data
>
> 1. In **My Workspace**, select **Get data**. You can also change to a group workspace, if one is available.
>
> [image]
>
> 2. Select Databases & More.
>
> [image]
>
> 3. Select **SQL Server Analysis Services** > **Connect**.
>
> [image]
>
> 4. Select a server. If you don't see any servers listed here, it means either a gateway, and data source, are not configured, or your account
>      is not listed in the **Users** tab of the data source, in the gateway.
>      Check with your adminsitrator.
> 5. Select the model you want to connect to. This could be either Tabular or Multidimensional.
>
> After you connect to the model, it will appear in your Power BI site
>   in **My Workspace/Datasets**. If you were swtiched to a group
>   workspace, then the dataset will appear within the group.
>
> [image]

Comment: This answer is about SQL Server Analysis Services, but the question seems to be about SQL Server (the database)

Comment: How come you accepted this as the answer? You never mention SSAS in your question, only SQL Server.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the on-premises Gateway to refresh data in a published Power BI data set with on-premise data like SQL Server data. Take a look at https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/gateway/

The gateway is free, there is a personal and an enterprise flavor and it should run on a machine that is always on, so you can schedule data refresh to occur automatically.